# Specific Formatter for NSString to NSDate Conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have been stuck on this for a while, and while I do believe the code I have is in working order, I am unable to convert the following string into a date due to being unable to set NSDateFormatter correctly.

2014-06-09T23:24:00.0000000

Here is some sample code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-06-09T23:24:00.0000000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

In this example, the log will turn up null.

Comment: Your format string doesn't match your date string's actual format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your date has a fractional part, you need to add that to the date formatter, otherwise you're not giving it what it expects. Add `.SSS` to the end of your format string, so your code will look like this, and return the date you expect:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-06-09T23:24:00.0000000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Prints: `2014-06-10 06:24:00 +0000`